# spark version 3.1.1 job stuck

Tags: apache-spark

I am running spark 3.1.1 using spark-submit
The app opens HTTP interface and I am sending it tasks.

the first run works great but the second one I send just stuck without any error in the log.

the UI is responsive and from the executor tab I can see:

```
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:426)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:194)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1(SparkPlan.scala:193)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$Lambda$5710/2015474824.apply(Unknown Source)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$Lambda$4150/1031027984.apply(Unknown Source)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeBroadcast(SparkPlan.scala:189)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.doExecute(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:142)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$Lambda$4148/1862342205.apply(Unknown Source)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$Lambda$4150/1031027984.apply(Unknown Source)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
```

Doing the same with spark 2.4.7 all works great.
What could be the problem?